# Prove or disprove: $\frac{n}{2} < f(n) + 1 < n$, for all $n \in A$ with $n \ge 8$

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing

Define the following function and sets:

1. $\mathbb{P} := \text{set of positive prime numbers in } \mathbb{Z}^+$
2. $A := \{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \, \mid \, n \ge 4 \, \wedge \, n \equiv 0 \bmod 2\}$
3. Function $f:A \to \mathbb{P}$ such that $f(n) = \max \{p \in \mathbb{P} \, \mid \, p \le n-2\}$

If $n \in A$, then $\frac{n}{2} < f(n) + 1 < n$

I tried the following proof (which may be incorrect):

**Proof by Induction:**

Denote the boolean true and false as $T$ and $F$, respectively. Let $P(n) = $ "Is $f(n)+1$ between $\frac{n}{2} < f(n) + 1 < n \text{?}$".$.

*Base Case for $n=4$:* Since $f(4) = 2$, then $2 < 2 + 1 = 3 < 4$. Hence, $P(4) = T$.

*Assume holds for $n=k$ (Induction Hypothesis):* Let $f(k) = p$ and $f(k+2) = q$. Suppose that $P(k) = T:$ $$\frac{k}{2} < p + 1 < k$$

*Show $n = k+2$ holds:* That is, $$\frac{k+2}{2} < q + 1 < k+2$$

Note: $q \le (k+2) - 2 = k$. So, $q+1 \le k + 1 < k+2$.

Also, $p \le q$.

Case 1: $p = q$

$$\begin{split}
\frac{k}{2} < p &\Longrightarrow \frac{k}{2} + 1 - 1 < p = q\\
&\Longrightarrow \frac{k+2}{2} < q + 1
\end{split}$$

Case 2: $p < q$

Since $\frac{k}{2} < p$, this implies that $\frac{k}{2} + 1 < p + 1 < q + 1$. Hence, $$ \frac{k+2}{2} < q+1 = f(k+2) + 1$$

Putting this all together, we have that $\frac{k+2}{2} < q + 1 < k + 2$. Thus, $P(k+2) = T$.

**Q.E.D.**

**Question:** Is this proof correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this proof doesn't work. You've done most of the setup correctly, but the tricky part will be Case 1 ($p = q$) and you've made a mistake there which made it seem trivial. In particular, you accidentally started from the assumption $\frac k 2 < p$, but the induction hypothesis actually only lets you assume $\frac k 2 < p+1$.

If you didn't see your mistake right away, one other way you could have known there must be a mistake somewhere is - you haven't used the information about prime numbers at all yet!

---

By the way, it would be good to include in your question more context on where this problem came from / why you care about it. If it's related to a class, then you could say what the course is about and what material has been covered recently that could be relevant. In fact, this seems to be a [pretty well-known problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) and there's a whole [separate Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Bertrand%27s_postulate) devoted to a pretty long and messy proof, which makes me suspect that something weird is going on if you're in a situation where it seems reasonable to try to prove this result using a "simple" induction method.